# How do you prove that category of representations of $G_m$ is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional graded vector spaces?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

$G_m$ is the multiplicative algebraic groups. I don't have much experience with dealing with this category of finite dimensional graded vector spaces, and only know the basics about what its objects look like. I'd appreciate if anyone can explain how to prove this, or cite a reference where I can look at the proof.

Comment: IIRC The basic gist is that the characters of Gm are indexed by the natural numbers, and you put this in bijection with degree of the grading... And use Schur's lemma to show that morphisms are compatible.

Comment: @AreaMan Thank you so much. I have to look up Schur's lemma since it has been a long time since I've seen it and try to work-out the details.

Comment: I don't know how you're setting up the representation theory of algebraic groups, but you can do this by writing down very carefully what a comodule over the coordinate ring looks like.

Comment: @Mark All I mean by that is that the (G-module) Homs between the different one-dimensional representations are 0 or isomorphisms. This is pretty easy to see by using linearity and the action of the group.